# Android - Center Gallery elements vertically

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm using a library called `FancyCoverFlow` which extends `Gallery`. I tried adding :

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in the layout to center child elements with no luck. The gallery is stretched on the entire screen, I made its background red to make sure.
How do you center Gallery child elements vertically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is no longer maintained but I'm posting the solution anyway.
The specific line you have to modify is the last one in the method `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` in `FancyCoverFlowItemWrapper` class :

From :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(this.wrappedViewBitmap, (float)((this.getWidth() - childView.getWidth()) / 2), 0, this.paint);
```

To :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(this.wrappedViewBitmap, (float)((this.getWidth() - childView.getWidth()) / 2), (float)((this.getHeight() - childView.getHeight()) / 2), this.paint);
```

Just instead of drawing the view at `top = 0` you calculate the middle and use it instead.
`FancyCoverFlowItemWrapper` instantiation resides in `FancyCoverFlowItem` class, so normally you would extend it and override the said method, but it's not public, so you have no access to it.

I ended up **duplicating** instead or extending the classes :

- FancyCoverFlow -> MyFancyCoverFlow
- FancyCoverFlowAdapter -> MyFancyCoverFlowAdapter
- FancyCoverFlowItemWrapper -> MyFancyCoverFlowItemWrapper

So now in my xml I don't use FancyCoverFlow anymore but **My**FancyCoverFlow instead.

Here's a fork of the fixed bug :
https://github.com/Mehdiway/FancyCoverFlow

Answer (score 0):

I tried this lib like you, but no luck. So I suggest you just put it inside a layout (RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, LinearLayout...) with match parent width and height, then set paddingTop to your FancyCoverFlow.

Comment: I refuse to surrender. I'm now digging into the source code wish me luck.

Comment: Goodluck and come back when you done with better solution. Thanks !